# New Bootstrap doesn't support carousels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, version

I have been having issues with using bootstrap's carousel.
I use `4.0.0` under the MaxCDN CDN, but if I use `4.3.1` (latest), carousels don't slide to other pictures.

This is the snippet I use to test :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/cuisine.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cuisine.css">
    <title>La Bonne Cuisine</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
                <p>The whole caption will only show up if the screen is at least medium size.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

</html>
```

What works :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

What doesn't work :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Now, I should use `4.0.0`, right? However, it feels counter-intuitive to use an older version just to have pictures slide in a carousel.

Comment: Have created a jsfiddle and works fine. what browser are you using ?

Comment: I've tried with edge with chromium, chrome and firefox. I'm using apache and its for a php page

Comment: Your example using `4.3.1` and it works. Try to run snippet

Comment: Even in the snippet, its working good. Did you see that ??

Comment: It does work, but it doesn't slide to other pictures as if I used 4.0.0

Comment: In your code snippet you use 4.3.1 and works fine, even in a js fiddle.

Comment: Does it slide for you? @Sfili_81

Comment: @Shadow4499 yes. Are you sure to use the correct bootstrap js?

Comment: Ok. Then I still don't know why, on my end, fiddle and two different browser engines just don't work on 4.3.1. Anyway, thank you all.

Comment: @Sfili_81 The same one that is included in the snippet, yes. EDIT : They seem to be different versions, I'll retry with same version on both

Comment: share your fiddle so we can see why it doesn't work

Comment: @Sfili_81 https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=yOh4HqxL4G

Comment: @Sfili_81 https://jsfiddle.net/1kptyaqc/ Sorry, it's my first time using stack overflow and didnt know about fiddle lol

Comment: @Sfili_81 did my fiddle make the images slide?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Sorry to bother you one last time, but I did try on my laptop and it works just fine. It's just my desktop PC that does this. very weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by myself.

Apparently, if you turn off animations in Windows 10, your carousels won't have the pictures slide.